# Passing function as an argument: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As functions in Python are objects so we can pass them into other functions. For example:

```
def hello(x) :
    return "Hello World"*x
def bye(x) :
    return "Bye World"*x
def analyze(func,x) :
    return func(x)
```

For `analyze(bye, 3)` OUTPUT is `Bye WorldBye WorldBye World`

For `analyze(hello, 3)` OUTPUT is `Bye World WorldHello World`

It makes sense but while doing the same in-class Objects it throws an error. For example:

```
class Greetings:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def hello(self, x) :
      return "Hello World"*x
   def bye(self, x) :
      return "Bye World"*x
   def analyze(self, func, x) :
      return self.func(x)
```

Driver Code:

```
obj = Greetings()
obj.analyze(hello, 3)
```

Throws `TypeError: analyze() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

I even tried `obj.analyze(obj, hello, 3)`

Then it throws `AttributeError: type object 'Greetings' has no attribute 'func'` exception.

Comment: `self.func` accesses the attribute literally named `func`, which doesn't exist. Also you're passing the previously-defined `func` function, not the name of the method you want to call (i.e. a string). The dupe tells you how to access the method by name, but you'll have to change what you're calling `obj.analyze` with too.

Comment: I get "Name error: 'hello' not defined". it should be `obj.hello` or `Greetings.hello`. (Or if the other functions are still in scope, you should get "'Greetings' object has no attribute 'func'".)

Comment: @tobias_k I assume the original function is still in scope

Comment: Actually, your errors sound more like you accidentally did `obj = Greetings` instead of `obj = Greetings()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
class Greetings:
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def hello(self, x) :
      return "Hello World"*x

   def bye(self, x) :
      return "Bye World"*x

   def analyze(self, func, x) :
      return func(x)

obj = Greetings()
print(obj.analyze(obj.hello, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Greetings:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def hello(self, x) :
      return "Hello World"*x
   def bye(self, x) :
      return "Bye World"*x
   def analyze(self, func, x) :
      return func(x)

obj = Greetings()
obj.analyze(obj.hello, 3)
```

Comment: Please add explanation for quality and long term value.

Comment: You used  return self.func(x) but you your class has no function named func.

Comment: hello is inside a class so you use instance of class.function